# Is $x(x!)^{1/x}$ an increasing function of $x$, for $x > 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, functional-inequalities

Is $x(x!)^{1/x}$ an increasing function of $x$, for $x > 0$?

Here $x!$ is the factorial of $x$.

Sure, I do know differential calculus, but my problem is that I do not know how to compute for the derivative of $x!$.

Lastly, I asked [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+x%28x%21%29%5E%281%2Fx%29+for+x+%3E+0) to plot the function
$$f(x)=x(x!)^{1/x}$$
and it does appear to be increasing.

Is it possible to prove this fact rigorously?  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe defining $x!$ using the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\log f(x) = \log x + \frac{1}{x}\log\Gamma(x+1) $$
and $\log x$ is increasing, hence it is enough to show that $\frac{1}{x}\log\Gamma(x+1)$ is increasing. However:

$$\frac{1}{x}\log\Gamma(x+1) = \frac{\log\Gamma(x+1)-\log\Gamma(0+1)}{x-0} $$
is increasing since $\log\Gamma$ is convex by the [Bohr-Mollerup theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Jack!  =)

Comment: @ArnieDris: you're welcome.

Comment: You can also use this approach with $\ln x! \sim x \ln x - x$

Answer (score 2):

If $x \in \mathbb Z^+$, the proof is simpler. Let $f(x) = (x!)^\frac{1}{x}$, for $x \in \mathbb Z^+$. Then, $f(x)>0$ and $\displaystyle \Big(\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}\Big)^{x(x+1)}= \frac{((x+1)!)^x}{(x!)^{x+1}}= \frac{(x!)^{x}(x+1)^x}{(x!)^{x+1}} = \frac{(x+1)^x}{x!} =\prod_{i = 1}^{x} \frac{x+1}{i} > 1$, since it's the non-empty product of reals > 1. Thus, $\displaystyle \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}> 1$, since $x(x+1) > 0$. Hence, $f(x)$ is strictly increasing. Therefore, $xf(x)$ is strictly increasing.